# Is it possible to reduce the amount of server calls made in case of Ajax drop down implmentation

Tags: jquery

I am working on Auto populate of **State , City ,Area and Location** using `jquery` Autosuggestions using  http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Currently i achivied it this way

```
<div id="addNewAddress">
<div class="stTime fields">
<input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Write Location">
<textarea id="writeaddreddss" class="ads" placeholder="Write Address"></textarea>
<input id="state" type="text" class="autosuggetate" placeholder="State">
<input id="city" type="text" class="autosuggecity" placeholder="City">
<input id="area" type="text" class="autosuggestarea" placeholder="Area">
<input id="locality" type="text" class="autosuggestlocality" placeholder="Locality">
<a id="saveaddress" class="btn btn-success per100">Save</a>
</div>
```

// Code For displaying state Auto suggestions

```
function SearchState(responsesss) {
    var states =[] ;
    for(var i=0;i<responsesss.length;i++)
    {
        states.push(responsesss[i].state);
    }
    $( ".autosuggetate" ).autocomplete({
        source: states
    });
}

$(document).on('keyup', '.autosuggetate', function() {
    var state = $(this).val();
    if(state.length>=3)
    {
        $.ajax({
            success: function (responsesss) {
                if(responsesss.length>0)
                {
                    SearchState(responsesss);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

// Code  For City Auto Suggestions


function SearchCity(responsesss) {
    var city =[] ;

        for(var i=0;i<responsesss.length;i++)
        {
            city.push(responsesss[i].city);
        }

    $( ".autosuggecity" ).autocomplete({
        source: city
    });
}

$(document).on('keyup', '.autosuggecity', function() {
    var city = $(this).val();
    var state = $("#state").val();
    if(state!=''&&city.length>=3)
    {
          $.ajax({
            success: function (responsesss) {
                if(responsesss.length>0)
                {
                    SearchCity(responsesss);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

// **Similarly I have code for Area and Locality too .**

Everything is working fine , except that i am worried about the amount of server calls that are being made to the back end .

Is there anyway to group the data and show that locally than making a back end call every time ??

Comment: You aren't using this implementation: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote
use the `delay` parameter. http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-delay

Answer (score 0):

That's an idea and just an algorithm I'm a java developper and I don't really do javascript.

1. Wait for 3 character to start searching (you did that already)
2. Store in a  "object" the values retrieved from your server
3. Then look if your storage  object contain the 3 first characters typed in
4. if it does then look in your values list
5. else retrieve from server and store it.

Hope that's help
Bye